# HParams in Tensorboard, Run IDs and naming

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensorboard

I'm using `SummaryWriter.add_hparams(params, values)` to log hyperparameters during training of my Seq2Seq model. My runs are named with a timestamp like `2020-09-10 14-50-27`. In the HParams tab in Tensorboard, everything looks fine, but the HParam Trial IDs are different; they have another string of numbers attached like this: `2020-09-10 14-50-27/1599742915.9712806`. These also appear in the Scalar tab as different runs, which is quite inconvenient. Is there a way to turn of this extra naming or to stop them of appearing in the Scalars tab? I use pytorch and its summarywriter like this:

```py
params = {
    'max_epochs' : max_epochs,
    'learning_rate': learning_rate,
    'batch_size': batch_size,
    'optimizer_name': optimizer_name,
    'dropout_fc': dropout_fc
}
values = {
    'hparam/hp_total_time': t1_stop - t0_start,
    'hparam/score' : best_score
}

tb.add_hparams(params, values)
```

Comment: Can you add a standalone code to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 2):

As Aniket mentioned there is not enough in your issue description to be entirely sure what the issue is.

However, if you are using Pytorch, I suspect you may be referring to the behaviour also reported in [this issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/32651). The `add_hparams` method creates a new subfolder with current timestamp when called, which is `1599742915.9712806` in your case.
TensorBoard uses the hierarchical folder structure to organise (group) runs, which is why `2020-09-10 14-50-27/1599742915.9712806` and `2020-09-10 14-50-27` appear as different runs.

As per the issue I mentioned above, there does not seem to be an "official" way to modify this behaviour but if you read the comments you will find a few custom classes that have been proposed to help.